Area of Cassini Oval
I am trying to find the area of the cassini oval, whose parametric and polar equations can be found here. To verify the result of area of Cassini Oval in the case $b>a$ written in Wolfram, I computed the integral using parametric equations. The domain can be written as $u = r h(t) \cos{t}$, $v = r h(t) \sin{t}$ where $0\le r\le 1, 0 \le t \le 2\pi$  and $h(t)^2 = a^2\cos{2t}+\sqrt{b^4-a^2\sin^{2}(2t)}$. The Jacobian came out to be $r h(t)^2$, so the area is $$ \int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{1} rh(t)^2 drdt = \frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\sqrt{b^4-a^2\sin^2{2t}}dt = 2b^2 \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\sqrt{1-\left(\frac{a}{b^2}\right)^2\sin^2{t}}dt.$$
Thus the area came out to be $2b^2 E\left(\frac{a}{b^2}\right)$ where $E$ is the Elliptic Integral of the Second Kind. This however doesn't match with the answer given in the webpage. Am I doing something wrong?
Edit 1 : I think the parametric equation is incorrect given in the 1st link.. I beileve $h(t)^2 = a^2\cos{2t}+\sqrt{b^4-a^4\sin^{2}(2t)}$, but that will change the answer to $2b^2 E\left(\frac{a^2}{b^2}\right)$ which still doesn't match wolfram's answer.

You are correct that the parametric equation in the first link has an error, and that the polar distance function should satisfy $$r^2(\theta) = a^2 \cos 2\theta \pm \sqrt{b^4 - a^{\color{red}4} \sin^2 2\theta}. \tag{1}$$  Then $$(x(\theta), y(\theta)) = (r(\theta) \cos \theta, r(\theta) \sin \theta). \tag{2}$$  In the case $b > a$, we take the positive root of $(1)$ and the enclosed area may be written
$$\begin{align}
A(a,b) &= \int_{\theta = 0}^{2\pi} \frac{1}{2} r(\theta)^2 \, d\theta \\
&= \frac{1}{2} \int_{\theta=0}^{2\pi} a^2 \cos 2\theta + \sqrt{b^4 - a^4 \sin^2 2\theta} \, d\theta \\
&= \frac{1}{2} \int_{\theta=0}^{2\pi} \sqrt{b^4 - a^4 \sin^2 2\theta} \, d\theta \\
&= 4b^2 \int_{\theta=0}^{\pi/4} \sqrt{1 - \frac{a^4}{b^4} \sin^2 2\theta} \, d\theta \\
&= 2b^2 E(a^4/b^4), \tag{3}
\end{align}$$
where $$E(m) = \int_{\theta=0}^{\pi/2} \sqrt{1 - m \sin^2 \theta} \, d\theta \tag{4}$$ is the complete elliptic integral of the second kind.  Note that the definition used in the referenced link has $m = k^2$, so the argument returned by Wolfram Alpha (and Mathematica) is $a^4/b^4$, not $a^2/b^2$.  This is presumably the source of your discrepancy; i.e., Wolfram Alpha uses $(4)$ but Wikipedia uses $$E(k) = \int_{\theta=0}^{\pi/2} \sqrt{1 - k^2 \sin^2 \theta} \, d\theta.$$

Thank you for your answer. Wolfram has added $a^2$ in their area, is that incorrect? Their area is $a^2+b^2E(a^2/b^2)$ or $a^2+b^2E(a^4/b^4)$ if we use your definition.

@Sam The case $a = 2$, $b = 3$ should yield an area greater than $20$ because the oval encloses the integer lattice points $(3,0)$, $(3,1)$, $(2,2)$, and $(0,2)$, so the area in each quadrant must be greater than $5$.  My result gives an area of approximately $26.8216$ but the area given by the alternate formula is only $17.4108$.

@Sam I have noticed another error in the first web page.  The RHS of the implicit equation should read $b^4$, not $b^2$.
